# How to use drop down list with range of dates (years) by specific year in Excel

Tags: excel, dropdown

I want to create conditional drop down list when user fill the year in column A and in column B is filled the range which is taken from list defined in column E.
How can I do it?

[image: Range of years list]

Comment: To me it is not clear: should the value of B3 be selected from a drop down list? But why? There is only one valid entry for year 1951. Wouldn't it make more sense to have a formula that calculates the correct year-range? On the other hand: List in column E as a lot of gaps ... is this by intention?

Comment: User will write the year in A3 and in B3 should appear relevant year range. Actually for me it would be better if user just selected from drop down menu but they want it to work this way. And yes these gaps are intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which requires a few helper columns

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkgqRfHIC5Alfyiof2VQ?e=5RehGh

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(J3;4))
=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(J3;4))
=L3-K3
=NUMBERVALUE(K3)
=IF(($N3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($M3)-1)<=$L3;$N3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($M3)-1;0)


=IF(COUNTIF($N$3:$Z$17;A4)=1;A4;"")
=OFFSET($C$4;;;COUNTIF(C4:$C$1000;">1");1)
=INDEX($J$3:$L$8;MATCH(E3;$K$3:$K$8;1);1)
```

Replace semicolon with komma if your local Excel version needs it.

You could combine some formulas to have less helper columns.

[image]

Chose from Drop Down menue

[image]

Comment: Thank you...this is just awesome solution. Really appreciate it.